# MATLAB - objects not clearing when timers are involved

Tags: oop, matlab, timer

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9559849/238644), but not quite.

I have two classes, `FunctionWrapper` and `TimerWrapper`:

```
classdef FunctionWrapper < handle
    methods
        function Fcn(obj)
            disp('FunctionWrapper.Fcn was called!');
        end
    end
end

classdef TimerWrapper < handle
    properties
        Timer
    end

    methods
       function obj = TimerWrapper(other_object)
            obj.Timer = timer;
            set(obj.Timer, 'Period', 1);
            set(obj.Timer, 'ExecutionMode', 'fixedSpacing');
            set(obj.Timer, 'TimerFcn', @(event, data) other_object.Fcn);
       end

       function start(obj)
           start(obj.Timer);
       end

       function stop(obj)
           stop(obj.Timer);
       end

       function delete(obj)
           disp('destructor called!');
           delete(obj.Timer);
       end
    end
end
```

Say I execute the following code in the Command Window:

```
>> F = FunctionWrapper;
>> T = TimerWrapper(F);
>> clear T %# T's destructor not called
>> timerfind %# just to verify that no, the destructor was never called

   Timer Object: timer-1

   Timer Settings
      ExecutionMode: fixedSpacing
             Period: 1
           BusyMode: drop
            Running: off

   Callbacks
           TimerFcn: @(event,data)other_object.Fcn
           ErrorFcn: ''
           StartFcn: ''
            StopFcn: ''
```

What's going on here? I know that `timer` objects need to be manually deleted, but I thought that would be dealt with in the destructor for `TimerWrapper`. Without using [Amro's ugly but straightforward workaround to overload the `clear` command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9560715/238644), is there a way to `clear T` from the workspace? Furthermore, nothing is referring to `T`, so why does a reference to it exist? (The fact that the destructor is never called implies this fact.) Is this buried in the timer object itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type `t = TimerWrapper; f = functions(t.Timer.TimerFcn); f.workspace(2)`, you'll see that the workspace of the anonymous function used for the callback contains a reference to the `TimerWrapper` object itself. So there's a kind of circular reference there which is not picked up by `clear`.

Given how you've set things up, you can remove `T` (and its underlying timer object) by calling the destructor explicitly and then calling `clear`.

```
T.delete
clear T
```

The difference between `clear` and `delete` is kind of confusing (to me, anyway). As you've found, `clear` doesn't explicitly call the destructor. It just removes the *name* `T` from the workspace. So `T`, and its underlying timer, still exist at that point. If they contained no references to things that still existed, MATLAB would then remove `T` properly, including calling its destructor. As it is, since the timer contains a reference (in its callback) to `T`, which still exists, the timer (and thus `T` as well) is not deleted.

You can find it (despite not having a name in the workspace) with `timerfindall`, and if you explicitly delete it yourself using

```
tmrs = timerfindall;
delete(tmrs);
```

you'll find that `T` is now properly gone.

I'm not so sure that this is a bug, although I find it pretty confusing, and the distinction between `clear` and `delete` could probably be documented better.

As to a workaround, I don't find it a big pain to explicitly call `delete`, although it's a bit more of a pain to clean things up if you accidentally call `clear`. I would think the suggestion in message #5 from the [thread](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/306641) you linked to, rather than message #4, would be more general and robust.

I don't think you should overload `clear` in the way @Amro [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9560715/238644) in the separate thread you linked to: although this may work if you call `clear T` explicitly, you may still get into trouble if you call `clear all`, or `clear variables`. (I haven't tried it just now, but I believe these syntaxes of `clear` don't even loop over things in the workspace and call `clear` on each - instead they call the `clear` method of the internal MATLAB workspace object, and that's going to get confusing fast).

Comment: I actually removed the reference to `F` entirely and just used `disp` for the callback to test this out. It still doesn't clear on its own properly.

Comment: But if you type T.delete, followed by clear T, that works, right?

Comment: Yes, it does. This is the right way to do it, but my code base is huge and my users (actually, most MATLAB users) have no idea that `delete` and `clear` are two different things. Anyhow, I am still trying to understand why having a `TimerFcn` yields this behavior (assuming it's not a bug, which I think it is).

Comment: OK - I think I have a clearer explanation. Make a version of `TimerWrapper` that has `@(~,~)disp('hello')` as the `TimerFcn`, and type `t = TimerWrapper`. Now type `f = functions(t.Timer.TimerFcn)` and `f.workspace(2)`. You'll see that the workspace of the anonymous function used for the timer callback contains a reference to the TimerWrapper object itself. So there's a kind of circular reference there (whether or not `F` is referenced), which is not getting picked up by `clear`.

Comment: if you edit your answer to include that information, I'll award the checkmark + 50 bounty!

Comment: Here's one further idea. Give `TimerWrapper` a static method `fcn = maketimerfcn(obj)`, which defines `fcn` as `@(event,data)obj.Fcn`. Then set the timer's `TimerFcn` o `TimerWrapper.maketimerfcn(other_object)`. Because the anonymous function gets created in a workspace where the main `TimerWrapper` object doesn't exist, there's no circular reference, and the destructor gets called as you want it to.

Comment: the minimum bounty I can offer is 100.. I thought it was 50 :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though this might be because the timer's callback is set to a non-default value. [A proposed workaround](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/306641) (see message#4 of the linked thread) is to set the callback function only when the `start` method is called, then setting it to null when the `stop` method is called.