# Matlab: Class destructor not called during clear?

Tags: oop, matlab, destructor

In Matlab I have a class

```
classdef myClass
    properties
       % some properties here...
    end
    methods ( Access = 'public' )
        function obj = myClass()
            % constructor...
        end
        function obj = delete( obj )
             % suppose to be destructor...
             fprintf(1, 'delete\n');
        end
    end % public methods
end
```

What is the default behavior of Matlab when I `clear` a variable of type `myClass`?
For example:

```
>> m = myClass();
>> clear m
```

I would expect Matlab to call the destructor of `m` at this stage, but it seems like it doesn't!!

**My questions:**

1. How can I force a call to the destructor when `clear`ing a variable?
2. Is this default behavior of Matlab's makes any sense? Isn't it more logical to call the destructor when `clear`ing a variable?
3. Is it possible that Matlab's classes do not have a detructor method (that is, there is no default method to be called when the class is destroyed)? Or am I missing something?
4. Is it possible that only classes derived from `handle` have a destructor (the `delete` method)?

Thanks!

**EDIT :** following [Jonas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057698/1714410), a brief summary:

Matlab has two types of classes: [value classes (the default)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/user-defined-classes.html) and [handle classes (derived from `handle` super class)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html). Value classes tends to provide better performance, however, they do not have a destructor functionality.

`handle` classes do have a destructor function: `delete` that is called when the class is destroyed. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236649/matlab-run-object-destructor-when-using-clear) from more details on `handle` class destructors.

If one wishes to have a destructor-like functionality for value classes, Jona's answer proposes a method utilizing `onCleanup` functionality.

Thanks for the good answer and the insightful comments!

Comment: Possible dubplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7236649/matlab-run-object-destructor-when-using-clear

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin - I suspect these two questions are related, but not duplicates, as the discussion there involved classes derived from the `handle` superclass.

Comment: I agree with Shai, it's a different (and interesting) issue.

Comment: The bottom of this page seems to have some relevant info for your final questions. http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/matlab_oop/handle-class-destructors.html

Comment: Another issue with MATLAB OOP: Simple assignment operator (e.g. A=B) cannot be overloaded. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @PavelHoloborodko see: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/158254

Comment: MATLAB doesn't call the class constructor in simple assignment like A = B.   At least for value objects

Comment: @PavelHoloborodko I guess you need to work with `handle` classes to get this functionality.

Comment: Same for handle classes. Assignment is not allowed to overload at all.

Comment: @PavelHoloborodko it seems like instead of overloading the assignment operator, you need to implement a copy constructor and replace `a=b` with `a(b)`.

Comment: Well, I have no control over the user code. I just supply my new data type and existing code should work with it without changes thanks to overloaded operators (the C++ OOP style). Here is what I do: http://www.advanpix.com/  Restriction on overloading the assignment operator makes OOP in MATLAB very inefficient, if it can be called OOP at all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Delete](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/handle.delete.html) is only defined as class destructor for handle classes, not value classes (so the answer to Q4 is "yes", see the previous link to the documentation). Value classes work very much like standard Matlab arrays, in that they're passed by value rather than by reference, and in that many of the internals, such as destructors, are hidden from the user. In exchange, they're usually faster (see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1446281/matlabs-garbage-collector)).

Consequently, I suggest to use the [onCleanup](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/oncleanup.html) functionality if you want to have a delete method being called (note that `delete(m)` will not actually delete anything, so you may want to make that a private method).

```
classdef myTestClass
    properties
       % some properties here...
    end
    properties (Hidden)
        cleanup
    end
    methods ( Access = 'public' )
        function obj = myTestClass()
            % constructor...
            obj.cleanup = onCleanup(@()delete(obj));
        end
    end 
    methods ( Access = 'private' )
        %# I suggest hiding the delete method, since it does not
        %# actually delete anything
        function obj = delete( obj )
             fprintf(1, 'delete\n');
        end
    end % public methods
end
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. However, isn't there a more straightforward way of defining a destructor that is called when a class instance is deleted / cleared? I'm more of a C++ OOP person, so I can't really see why Matlab is making this destructor thing so non-trivial...

Comment: @Shai: If you come from C++ OOP, I suggest using handle classes instead of value classes - the destructor works as expected, you pass by reference, both which are features you'd expect coming from C++.

Comment: @Shai: I've expanded my answer to explicitly touch questions 3 and 4.